# How can I list only local users on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

When I run "getent passwd", I receive a list of all users, like: local users and LDAP user. But, I would need to get only local users.

Comment: Have you tried the `--service files` option?

Answer (score 0):

André:

All non system users starts with a uid greater than or equals 1000 (uid >= 1000).

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F':' '( $3 >= 1000 ) {print $1}'
```

($3 is the uid column)

In my case, the libvirt-qemu user appears because it has uid 64055 and the reason is here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/897026/why-do-i-have-a-libvirt-qemu-account-in-lock-switch-account-options-in-ubuntu

Comment: I would like to use getent, but I solved with this command: awk -F":" '{print $1}' /etc/passwd

Comment: `awk -F":" '{print $1}' /etc/passwd ` will display all the first column of the  `/etc/passwd` file. Keep in mind that all users with uid less than 1000 are reserved for another things like system for administrative and system accounts, etc.